# How can i manage slurm log per user in slurm database

Tags: linux, mariadb, scheduler, slurm, hpc

Recently, i'm studying Slurm for cluster resource management. I've built small Slurm CPU cluster on KVM virtual machines for personal test and usage. It consists of four nodes and i split them into two same size partition. On the master node, there are three slurm users except root user. When i execute `srun` command on master node using each user account, the entire activities and logs are written onto `/var/log/slurmctld.log` and `/var/log/slurmdbd.log` on master node and `/var/log/slurmd.log` on worker nodes. In this way, it's hard for me to differentiate between users. For ease of mangement and analysis of logs, i want to manage logs separately user by user in MariaDB which is running on master node. Is there built-in functionality Slurm support for this? If not, how can i implement this functionality for myself?

Comment: What information related to the users are you looking for in the log files?

Comment: @damienfrancois
I want to track the logs of user activities such as kind of jobs and command users executed and start time, end time, etc.

Comment: the accounting infrastructure contains some of that information and you can query it user by user with `sacct`. would that work for you? otherwise I think using `grep` with the log file could also help